# compiling rviz on debian

Tags: ros, rviz, ros-fuerte, compilation, debian

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to compile rviz on fuerte running debian/amd64 sid.

I downloaded the package from the [wiki](https://github.com/ros-visualization/visualization.git).

Using rosmake leads to the following error:

```
$ rosmake visualization

[ rosmake ] rosmake 

starting...                                                                                                                                                 
[ rosmake ] Packages requested are: 

['visualization']                                                                     

...                                

cannot find required resource: rviz
```

Where can I download it ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/56133/compiling-rviz-on-debian/) by [Fabien R](https://answers.ros.org/users/2975/fabien-r/) on ROS Answers with karma: 90 on 2013-02-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In Fuerte, [rviz](http://ros.org/wiki/rviz) was part of the visualization stack, before version 1.9.x. Now, it is a separate package.

To get the correct version for Fuerte, check out the **fuerte** branch from git://github.com/ros-visualization/visualization.git.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-02-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Fabien R](https://answers.ros.org/users/2975/fabien-r/) on 2013-02-25**:
Finally, I found an older version and successfully compiled it, with slight modifications in some source files.